# Silverlight context menu: how to determine which menu was clicked?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7

I have the following context menu:

```
                <ListBox x:Name="sectionList" Margin="56,8,15,0" FontSize="64" SelectionChanged="SectionList_SelectionChanged">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                    <toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                        <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Hide this section from this list" Click="ContextMenuItem_Click" />
                                    </toolkit:ContextMenu>
                                </toolkit:ContextMenuService.ContextMenu>
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding DisplayName}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

As you can see, each displayed item has its own context menu. Each context menu is hooked up to the same event handler:

```
    private void ContextMenuItem_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

From this method, how can I tell which context menu was clicked? I want to know what the `DataContext` for the corresponding `DataTemplate` is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the item the ListBoxItem is bound to by casting the sender as a `FrameworkElement` to get access to the `DataContext`:

```
(sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext
```

You can then cast this to the appropriate model class and access the details you need. e.g.:

```
((sender as FrameworkElement).DataContext as ItemViewModel).DisplayName
```

Answer (score 1):

If you put a breakpoint inside the event handler `ContextMenuItem_Click,` you will then be able to examine the properties of `sender` and `e`. You will probably find your answer there.

One way to do this is to hover over those words. Another would be to use the Immediate Window. Type in `sender` and a dot to get intellisense.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `<StackPanel Tag="{Binding}">` then `((FrameworkElement)sender).Tag` will return the DataContext object (you'll have to cast it before use, of course).